# SQL Command Line Setup Failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

When running SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe directly SQL Installation Center shows up and I can install SQLEXPRESS just fine. I want to perform automatic command line install so I have done the SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /X to extract the files to my USB drive. I have no luck getting setup to run from command line or no idea how to trouble shoot. There are no logs produced in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log.

Command Line:

"D:#Setup Large Software Packages\SQLEXPRADV\setup.exe" /qs /ACTION=Install /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /ROLE=ALLFeatures_WithDefaults  /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN

Result:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: scenarioengine.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.2100.60
  Problem Signature 03: 4f35e1de
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4fee6afb
  Problem Signature 07: 366d
  Problem Signature 08: 10
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentNullException
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=190175

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

When batch terminates I get following:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.PreloadAssemblies()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Main()
```

I have followed:

[BLOG: SQL 2012 Unattended Install Scripts](http://www.derekseaman.com/2012/07/sql-2012-unattended-install-scripts.html) - did not work.

[MSDN: Install SQL Server 2012 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) - 100's of options could spend year playing with them.

**What is the correct command line to install SQLEXPRESS with ALL features after extracting files from SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something was wrong with files that were exploded from the SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe. After trying few times now it seams to work.